# Running Bokeh Server on Local Network

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a simple Bokeh app named `app.py` as follows:

```
### contents of app.py

from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.embed import server_document
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

doc = curdoc()
doc.add_root(plot)
```

I can run this app with the following command:

```
bokeh serve app.py
```

I can then access the plot through my web browser: `http://localhost:5006/app.`

However, I would like the plot to be available to all devices on my private network using their web browsers. How should I do this?

I've found the following command as a suggested solution, but it doesn't work as it states that my IP-address is not available.

```
bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin='ip address':'port number' my_app.py --port 'port number'
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command works on my local network with Bokeh v1.0.4. First the Bokeh server on IP:PORT = 192.168.1.208:5001 is started. This opens a new browser tab showing the app. Than you can see  a remote client is connecting on IP:POST = 192.168.1.201 (another computer) The plot is succesfuly being displayed in the browser on the remote computer.

```
bokeh serve --address 192.168.1.208 --port 5001 --allow-websocket-origin=192.168.1.201:5001 --allow-websocket-origin=192.168.1.208:5001 --show simple_app.py

2019-03-07 20:01:54,289 Starting Bokeh server version 1.0.4 (running on Tornado 4.5.3)
2019-03-07 20:01:54,294 Bokeh app running at: http://192.168.1.208:5001/simple_app
2019-03-07 20:01:54,295 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 49031
2019-03-07 20:01:54,581 200 GET /simple_app (192.168.1.208) 135.34ms
2019-03-07 20:01:54,694 101 GET /simple_app/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=Ino2U2RYLAJ9LQXIGgNmPXnRyZNJHZQcTEEfsX0bM3f9 (192.168.1.208) 0.82ms
2019-03-07 20:01:54,694 WebSocket connection opened
2019-03-07 20:01:54,695 ServerConnection created
2019-03-07 20:02:03,208 200 GET /simple_app (192.168.1.201) 24.19ms
2019-03-07 20:02:55,503 200 GET /simple_app (192.168.1.201) 24.17ms
2019-03-07 20:02:55,617 200 GET /static/css/bokeh.min.css?v=4c253f78f16b7d5d0c9d1df8062c7f4c (192.168.1.201) 7.32ms
2019-03-07 20:02:55,618 200 GET /static/css/bokeh-widgets.min.css?v=6f280acb818327130a8c244ce05fd10d (192.168.1.201) 0.64ms
2019-03-07 20:02:55,618 200 GET /static/css/bokeh-tables.min.css?v=86c18b0b1fd30cdbc124e60cb9452e73 (192.168.1.201) 0.59ms
2019-03-07 20:02:55,743 200 GET /static/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js?v=68fceb4be2f3d6410ff2d7704c8b87cf (192.168.1.201) 1.01ms
2019-03-07 20:02:55,890 200 GET /static/js/bokeh-gl.min.js?v=70e18d8dcea09947c12764bf85ec76a0 (192.168.1.201) 1.09ms
2019-03-07 20:02:56,222 200 GET /static/js/bokeh-tables.min.js?v=02bdadb2c698bc2855a4d4a69c163821 (192.168.1.201) 478.59ms
2019-03-07 20:02:56,636 200 GET /static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e (192.168.1.201) 896.20ms
2019-03-07 20:02:58,134 404 GET /favicon.ico (192.168.1.201) 0.55ms
2019-03-07 20:02:58,149 101 GET /simple_app/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=2CR07bJEIWPwWj07dPH3SSrou74mWgOwetucvIPuD3sk (192.168.1.201) 0.81ms
2019-03-07 20:02:58,149 WebSocket connection opened
2019-03-07 20:02:58,150 ServerConnection created
```

Comment: This answers works perfectly! I just have to add one thing that trippde me up: I had tried a similar solution, but it didn't work. However, after **turning off the firewall on the laptop I use as host**, it works. Thanks @Tony!